# How to extract parent folder from Pathlib Path using raw string path?

Tags: python, path

I want to extract the parent folder from a raw path string. For string without `r` prefix, I successfully extracted the file path.

```py
from pathlib import Path
des_dirs = '/path/to/my/file'
Path(des_dirs).parents[0]

Output:
> PosixPath('/path/to/my')
```

For a raw string, I'm unable to extract the parent folder. What am I missing here? Thanks!

```py
from pathlib import Path
des_dirs = r'C:\Users\pp\Desktop\IMAGE_DATA\resized\masks'
Path(des_dirs).parents[0]

Output:
> PosixPath('.')
```

A reproducible example [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iBO6X_HVEA9_hWbEf_wyYYYjpcgj1pkB?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the documentation, You could have known how to do that, the documentation says that explicitly.
It is literally the first section in the page.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

use `pathlib.PureWindowsPath`.

```py
from pathlib import PureWindowsPath
des_dirs = r'C:\Users\pp\Desktop\IMAGE_DATA\resized\masks'
print(PureWindowsPath(des_dirs).parents[0])
```

Result:
`C:\Users\pp\Desktop\IMAGE_DATA\resized`